# MSDTC is only working in one direction

Tags: transactionscope, msdtc

I'm trying to use `TransactionScope` for unit tests and I keep getting errors on our build server. After following several helpful SO answers and blogs, I installed [DTCPing](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2868) and ran it on both `server1` & `server2`. When I run it in the reverse order it seems to connect in one direction and fail in the other:

```
++++++++++++Validating Remote Computer Name++++++++++++
Please refer to following log file for details:
    D:\KPAHQDEV043372.log
Invoking RPC method on teamcity
RPC test is successful
++++++++++++RPC test completed+++++++++++++++
++++++++++++Start DTC Binding Test +++++++++++++
Trying Bind to teamcity
Binding call to teamcity Failed
Session Down
```

But when I run it in the intended direction it just fails the RPC

```
++++++++++++Validating Remote Computer Name++++++++++++
Please refer to following log file for details:
    C:\TEAMCITY3024.log
Invoking RPC method on kpahqdev04
Problem:fail to invoke remote RPC method
Error(0x6BA) at dtcping.cpp @303
-->RPC pinging exception
-->1722(The RPC server is unavailable.)
RPC test failed
```

I found some helpful info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2008/11/12/troubleshooting-msdtc-issues-with-the-dtcping-tool.aspx) but now I'm just stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure this will help you but it did help me. See the following link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a0f714e4-c278-4ec0-a471-fe5cf2f4b68b/transactionscope-fails?forum=windowstransactionsprogramming&prof=required

Pay attention on the part where he emphasizes on hosts file, and how many entries, and in which form.

Comment: Any solution to this? I have exactly the same problem. Ping and telnet to port 135 is fine in both directions, and DTC has exception rules on both firewalls but I still get error 1722.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Distributed Transaction Coordinator service as an exception in firewall.
Also make sure RPC (port 135) is enabled and added as en exception in firewall.

Also you can check if firewall is the culprit by turning off firewall and re-running the DTCPing.